# Using "divider" headers in a GridView with a "Group By" report

Tags: asp.net, sql, gridview

Not too sure how to explain this, so please bear with me!

I have a GridView with a SQL query bound to it. The query uses "Group By" to group together rows which have a particular "person" in the "Tech" column. E.g.

### Tech - Date - Notes

Fred - 01/12/10 - Rebooted machine
Fred - 02/12/10 - Cleared printer jam
Fred - 03/12/10 - Reset password
Susan - 02/12/10 - Changed permissions
Susan - 02/12/10 - Restarted machine

etc

I want to remove the "Tech" column and use a header before each group of rows instead. E.g.

### Date - Notes

*Fred*
01/12/10 - Rebooted machine
02/12/10 - Cleared printer jam
03/12/10 - Reset password

*Susan*
02/12/10 - Changed permissions
02/12/10 - Restarted machine

Can anyone give me some pointers on how I can acheive this?

Cheers,

Ben

Comment: Do you have to use a GridView? There are a number of simple ways to do what you're asking if something other than a GridView is used.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably better off changing the control to a [ListView](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020150712/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/010208-1.aspx).  It gives you more control over the content.